# Not Able To Install Stanford-Core-NLP Gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to install the [Stanford-Core-NLP gem](https://github.com/louismullie/stanford-core-nlp), which is one of the major projects on github for natural language processing using Ruby. It provides Ruby bindings for the Stanford-Core-NLP pakage, which where written in Java. When I try following the first step of the the installation instructions, which is:

```
gem install stanford-core-nlp
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing stanford-core-nlp:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby
extconf.rb:53:in `<main>': JAVA_HOME is not set. (RuntimeError)
```

I am running Ruby 1.9.2, which according to the repo, is the latest version the gem has been tested on and Java 1.7.0_40. I also tried looking for the mkmf.log file, but was unable to locate it.

Comment: Is your JAVA_HOME set?

Comment: @kristianp Thanks for the reply. To answer you're question, I don't think it was properly set. I just tried setting it based on three different tutorials, but I am still getting the same error message when I try to install the gem.

Comment: Which operating system are you running? What does `ruby -v` say?

Comment: @IanDickinson I am running Ubuntu 13.04. In the directory I was trying to install the gem, ruby -v is 1.9.2. In all my other directories I have rvm running 2.0.0 as my default.

Comment: @pweslow I'm in the same boat, what was your solution?

Comment: @GonZifroni I don't know, never got this one working. I suspect it does have something to do with JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because JAVA_HOME is getting reset in the sudo mode. To fix it, open your `/etc/sudoers` file add the following line and save it.

```
Defaults   env_keep += "JAVA_HOME"
```

now reopen the terminal and install the gem.

Answer (score 0):

I've been wrestling with this on Ubuntu. The thing that works reliably (though it is a sledgehammer) is:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/whatever gem install stanford-core-nlp
```

The installation script is sensitive to the format of JAVA_HOME - it shouldn't end in a slash character.